# Caching issues with TDBadgedCell

Tags: uitableview

This post is closely related to my previous post: [TDBadgedCell keeps caching the BadgeNumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201256/tdbadgedcell-keeps-caching-the-badgenumber)

The "badge" from TDBadgedCell keeps caching the numbers. A very simple example is shown here:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    TDBadgedCell *cell = (TDBadgedCell *)[_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[TDBadgedCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    }

    [cell setBadgeColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [cell setBadgeNumber:[indexPath row]];

    [[cell textLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:%@"%d", [indexPath row]]];

    return cell;
}
```

Anyone has any clue why this happens? The textLabel and detailTextLabel don't cache the data. Any additonal info would be welcome as well, as I seem to have a lot of issues with the caching of graphics in UITableViewCells. Any best practices or other useful information would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured this one out. Apparently I shouldn't use the default code to initialize my cell when using the TDBadgedCell. The following code:

```
TDBadgedCell *cell = (TDBadgedCell *)[_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[TDBadgedCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
}
```

Needs to be changed into this:

```
TDBadgedCell *cell = [[[TDBadgedCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

I am wondering if this is clean in terms of memory usage and such, but it'll do for now at least.

Answer (score 0):

I thought this was fixed in commit [2d255f075fe53ad10afe8eb65666207a8f2c65d0](https://github.com/tmdvs/TDBadgedCell/commit/2d255f075fe53ad10afe8eb65666207a8f2c65d0), which was made on March 22, 2013.  In my case, this initially seemed to fix the issue most of the time, but I still saw cached badges occasionally.  Then I realized that you can fix this once-and-for-all by using two different cells: when you need a badged cell, dequeue a TDBadgedCell, and when you don't need a badge, dequeue an ordinary UITableViewCell.